# unable to deploy sql clr stored procedure (unable to verify metadata)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlclr

I am trying to run the CREATE ASSEMBLY command for a SQL CLR (.Net 3.5) assembly on SQL Server 2008.  It returns a cryptic error message:

```
An error occurred while gathering metadata from assembly 'My.Awesome.Assembly' with HRESULT 0x80004005.
```

Why is it doing this, and how can I fix it without deploying it as UNSAFE?

---

steps I have done:

1. Followed all rules in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403273.aspx
2. Used no static fields
3. Have created 2 other SQL CLR assemblies that deploy just fine

Comment: Did you see contents of your assembly in ILDASM or Refelctor! may it be helpful.

Comment: Can you provide more information about code in the assembly? Also, see this article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189566.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what solved the problem for me; for future reference to anyone out there, SQL CLR stuff is very, *very* picky.

I had a constructor like this:

```
public MyObject(IEnumerable<T>  items)
{
    _innerItems = items.ToDictionary(i => i.Key);
}
```

I changed it to this:

```
public MyObject(IEnumerable<T>  items)
{
    _innerItems = new Dictionary<int, T>();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        _innerItems.Add(item.Key, item);
    }
}
```

And it was then able to deploy.  I then proceeded to pound my head against my desk.  Two methods, functionally equivalent; one works, and one has a cryptic deployment error message.